# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte when running webkit layouttests

Tags: python, utf-8, webkit

I succeeded Webkit window builds (WinLauncher and DumpRenderTree exe works.)

And I'm trying to Webkit layouttests on windows 7 64 bits.
`$ ./Tools/Scripts/run-webkit-tests --debug --driver-name=DumpRenderTree canvas`

I got some error.
I think it might be relate to my computer settings but not sure.
Webkit source has no problem because Webkit build-bot works properly layouttests.

My Python version : 2.7.8 (as http://www.webkit.org/building/tools.html)
Cygwin : Installed all packages
Build : VS2013 - debug - win32

**ERROR**

```
Using port 'win-future'
Test configuration: <future, x86, debug>
Placing test results in /home/user/myWebkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/bin32/layout-test-results
Baseline search path: win -> mac-mountainlion -> mac -> generic
Using Debug build
Pixel tests disabled
Regular timeout: 35000, slow test timeout: 175000
Command line: /home/user/myWebkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/bin32/DumpRenderTree -

--lint-test-files warnings:
LayoutTests/platform/win/TestExpectations:996 Path does not exist.         
    fast/multicol/newmulticol/compare-with-old-impl/hit-test-above-or-below.html
LayoutTests/platform/win/TestExpectations:2898 Unrecognized expectation "Timeout]" 
    tables/mozilla/marvin/backgr_simple-table-column.html

Found 801 tests; running 801, skipping 0.
Checking build ...
UnicodeDecodeError raised: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 374: invalid start byte
 ~ ~ ~ ~
```

In cygwin, my locale is

```
$ locale
 LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8
 LC_CTYPE="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_NUMERIC="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_TIME="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_COLLATE="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_MESSAGES="ko_KR.UTF-8"
 LC_ALL=
```

I added the following cmds and ran layouttests, but there was no change.

```
export LC_ALL=ko_KR.UTF-8
```

or  *ko_KR.utf8, "ko_KR.utf8"* ...

Comment: It could be that your cygwin environment is not set up correctly to support utf-8. What do you get when you run the command `locale` in cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
import os
```

can you add them and check? maybe it will help